How to debug why a pwsh7 URL regex does not match
I am working on a PowerShell Core 7 script, running in Windows environment.
Requirements of the regex:

Three or four part host addresses
The last two parts can be one of two options: specificPartA.specificPartB -or- specificPartC.specificPartD, so the last two parts must be one of two known values.
The first one or two parts cannot contain any numbers.

Examples:

foo.specificPartA.specificPartB - matches
foo.bar.specificPartA.specificPartB - matches
foo.specificPartC.specificPartD - matches
foo.bar.specificPartC.specificPartD - matches
foo1.specificPartC.specificPartD - doesn't match due to numbers (three parts)
foo1.bar.specificPartC.specificPartD - doesn't match due to numbers (four parts)

Current regex:
"[^0-9]+\.[^0-9]+\.(specificPartA.specificPartB|specificPartC.specificPartD)"

It fails here:
if ("foo.specificPartA.specificPartB" -match "[^0-9]+\.[^0-9]+\.(specificPartA.specificPartB|specificPartC.specificPartD)") { write-output "matches" } else { Write-Output "doesn't match" }

3 part should match but doesn't.
How can I fix it?
I am running variations of this a pwsh terminal this to test my regex:
if ("foo.specificPartA.specificPartB" -match "[^0-9]+\.[^0-9]+\.(specificPartA.specificPartB|specificPartC.specificPartD)") { write-output "matches" } else { Write-Output "doesn't match" }


You could assert the start of the string, followed by matching 1+ chars other than a digit or dot, and then match a dot.
Then you can optionally match the same pattern for the second part.
If you want a match only, you don't need capture groups and you have to escape the dot to match it literally.
^[^0-9.]+\.(?:[^0-9.]+\.)?(?:specificPartA\.specificPartB|specificPartC\.specificPartD)

See a regex demo.
if ("foo.specificPartA.specificPartB" -match "[^0-9.]+\.(?:[^0-9.]+\.)?(?:specificPartA\.specificPartB|specificPartC\.specificPartD)") { write-output "matches" } else { Write-Output "doesn't match" }

Output
matches


Thank you.  I'm starting to learn a bit more about regex, enough to be dangerous.  I have a question.  Would this be essentially the same thing, thinking I can eliminate the first part of the regex, since its essentially the same as the 2nd part, by using a plus + instead of a question mark ?, and is it wise to anchor the end with $? like this: ^(?:[^0-9]+\.)+(?:specificPartA\.specificPartB|specificPartC\.specificPartD)$

@JohnWeirich Yes you could also to that, but note that the + repeats 1 or more times. So the part ^(?:[^0-9]+\.)+ will first match all the dot separated parts, and will then try to fit in the last part of the regex. See https://regex101.com/r/nn6iOH/1 So there [^0-9.]+\.(?:[^0-9.]+\.)? can match 1 or 2 times, the ^(?:[^0-9]+\.)+ can match 1 or more times.

Gotcha.  So the answer to the question I posted was correct, I just asked the question wrong, because URLs in actuality are 3 or more parts, where the first part can be repeated any number of times.

There's built in url/uri validation that you can take advantage of, ex:
[uri] $ur1 = 'https://foo3.bar.cat.com' -- docs: System.Uri -- It supports file://, https://, UNC, and a bunch of others. Even ms-settings:sound
